# How do I get the response from a URLSession before the rest of my code executes?

Tags: json, swift, urlsession

I have a problem with my URLSession in Swift. No matter what I try (or how many tutorials I read through), I cannot find a way to get the network request to finish *before* executing the rest of my code. I was under the impression that a completion handler would do the trick, but this has not proven to be the case. What am I doing wrong here?

```
struct DataManager {
    
    let eventsURL = URL(string: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/blablabla/1/public/full?alt=json")!
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    var data = Data()
    
    func downloadEvents() -> [Event] {
        var events: [Event] = []
        var downloadedEvents: [[String: Any]] = []
        
        getDataFromServer(forURL: eventsURL) { result in
            downloadedEvents = result
        }
        
        // This next part always executes before the response is receive, which means the downloadedEvents variable is always empty.

        for downloadedEvent in downloadedEvents {
            if let event = Event(fromJSON: downloadedEvent) {
                events.append(event)
            }
        }
        
        return events
    }
    
    func getDataFromServer(forURL url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ result: [[String: Any]]) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let jsonData = data {
                let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
                if let dictionary = jsonObject as? [String: Any] {
                    if let feed = dictionary["feed"] as? [String: Any] {
                        if let entry = feed["entry"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                completion(entry)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `downloadEvents` function need to be asynchronous because its calls *another* asynchronous function `getDataFromServer`.

The solution may be to move the part for calculating Events to the asynchronous block and provide a completion parameter:

```
func downloadEvents(completion: @escaping ([Event]) -> ()) {
    var events: [Event] = []
    var downloadedEvents: [[String: Any]] = []

    getDataFromServer(forURL: eventsURL) { result in
        downloadedEvents = result
        for downloadedEvent in downloadedEvents {
            if let event = Event(fromJSON: downloadedEvent) {
                events.append(event)
            }
        }
        completion(events)
    }
}
```

---

**Note**

Your code may actually be simplified to:

```
func downloadEvents(completion: @escaping ([Event]) -> ()) {
    getDataFromServer(forURL: eventsURL) { completion($0.compactMap(Event.init(fromJSON:))) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue! I guess it takes some getting used to working with asynchronous requests, considering I can't have the function return a value like I normally would.